# How to prevent ListBox from autoselecting first item when using CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, listbox

I have a ListBox that's bound to a CollectionViewSource, and the textbox helps me filter out the collection.  However, the ListBox is autoselecting the first item.  How can I prevent the autoselect from happening?

Code:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="caseCollection" Source="{Binding Cases}"></CollectionViewSource>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="White" Height="50">
    <sdk:Label Name="lblWat">Enter a case</sdk:Label>
    <TextBox Width="150" Height="23" x:Name="caseSearch" TextChanged="caseSearch_TextChanged" />                    
</StackPanel>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource caseCollection}}" BorderThickness="0"  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AdminListBoxItemStyle}" 
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCase, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="lstCases"
                     SelectionMode="Single">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by setting [`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your `ListBox`

Comment: Isn't this by default false?

Comment: @RohitVats Its default value is `null`